# Trouble in drawing on Canvas (Android) in bounds

Tags: java, android, canvas, drawing, mobile-application

I'm making an alphabet draw app where users (normally kids) will be able to fill color in the alphabet images in the app...

I've made the app which enabled me to draw anything on the canvas using the code given below...

Main Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    SimpleDrawingView view;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        view = new SimpleDrawingView (this);

        setContentView(view);

                view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.a1);
    }
}
```

SimpleDrawingView class which actually draws on the view:

```
public class SimpleDrawingView extends View
 { 
    private final int paintColor = Color.BLACK;

    // defines paint and canvas
    private Paint drawPaint;

    // stores next circle
    private Path path = new Path();

    public SimpleDrawingView(Context context) { 
        super(context); 
        setFocusable(true); 
        setFocusableInTouchMode(true); 
        setupPaint();
    } 

    private void setupPaint() { 
        // Setup paint with color and stroke styles 
        drawPaint = new Paint(); 
        drawPaint.setColor(paintColor);
        drawPaint.setAntiAlias(true); 
        drawPaint.setStrokeWidth(15);
        drawPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        drawPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND); 
        drawPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
    } 

    @Override protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawPath(path, drawPaint);
    }

    @Override public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        float pointX = event.getX();
        float pointY = event.getY(); 

        // Checks for the event that occurs

        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: 
                path.moveTo(pointX, pointY);
                return true; 

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                path.lineTo(pointX, pointY);
                break;

            default: return false; }

            // Force a view to draw again 

            postInvalidate(); 
            return true; 
        } 
}
```

It let me fill in the alphabet but it draws on the whole screen/view. I want to let the user fill/draw on the alphabet only and not on the entire screen.

Can someone tell me what to do or atleast some guidelines to start it ?

Comment: @Mike M I've tried to add a custom view like the process mentioned in the answer of the link you provided. But the problem is same it draws on the entire screen and I want it to just fill in the alphabet and not the entire screen.

Comment: Oh, I thought you meant that you didn't want the drawing surface to be the whole `Activity`. But you mean you want to restrict the drawing to the shape of the letters?

Comment: Yes, I want to restrict the drawing on the alphabet, but the problem is when I add the view to the main layout it spreads up to the whole layout. I want it to draw only on the alphabet and not the entire screen.

Comment: did you get any solution?

Comment: @Viks no bro ..